# Can't POST data through AJAX/Fancybox to PHP file

Tags: php, ajax, fancybox

Hey I can't pass a JS variable through AJAX to php file. No matter if I try POST or GET it's not working: with POST it gave me [] or Undefined index if I want to print_r($_POST['adminID']
And GET, there I get {"fancybox":"true"}

```
$('#adminList tr').on('click', function() {
    var adminID = $(this).find(".adminID").text(); 
    console.log(adminID);
    $.ajax({
           type: 'POST',
           url: 'modules/management/user_edit.php',
           data: {adminID : adminID}, 
           success: function(data)
           {
                $.fancybox.open({
                src  : 'modules/management/user_edit.php',
                type : 'ajax'
                });
           }
    });
 });
```

and module/management/user_edit.php i just want to post this adminID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You send double request to `user_edit.php` file, first with POST data, and second without. You should display result of first request in fancybox.

```
$('#adminList tr').on('click', function() {
    var adminID = $(this).find(".adminID").text(); 
    $.ajax({
           type: 'POST',
           url: 'modules/management/user_edit.php',
           data: {adminID : adminID}, 
           success: function(response)
           {
                $.fancybox.open(response);
           }
    });
 });
```